# undefined method `original_filename' for uploading file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

undefined method `original_filename' for #.. this Error occur while i click on CreateProfile Button

## Controller

def createProfile
        return if params[:profile].blank?

```
    @profile = Profile.new
    @profile.upload_file = params[:profile]

    if @profile.save
        flash[:notice] = "Thank You for your submission"
        redirect_to profile_index_path
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Problem in your submission"
        render 'new'        
    end
end
```

## View

```
%h3 Apply For Job
=form_for :profile, url:{action: "createProfile"}, :multipart => true, html:{class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
    %div.form-group
        =f.label :data, 'CV', {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'}
        %div.col-lg-3
            =f.file_field :data, {:class => 'form-control'}
    %div.form-group
        %div.col-lg-offset-2.col-lg-10
            =f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary'
            = link_to profile_index_path do
                = content_tag :button, class: "btn btn-default" do
                    ="Cancel"
```

## Model

```
def upload_file=(imcoming_file)
        self.filename = imcoming_file.original_filename
        self.content_type = imcoming_file.content_type
        self.data = imcoming_file.read
    end

    def filename=(new_filename)
        write_attribute("filename", sanitize_filename(new_filename))
    end

    private
    def sanitize_filename(filename)
        just_filename = File.basename(filename)
        just_filename.gsub(/[^\w\.\-]/, '-')
    end
```

Why original_filename error occur...? any suggestion...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[:data]` at the end of the second line of your controller. `params[:profile]` provides a set of parameters related to the profile model from your form. In your case, only a parameter related to `'data'` is available. By adding `[:data]` to the line you are pointing the controller to that particular parameter.

Of course you will need to specify the directory you want to store your uploaded files. Ruby on Rails documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) provides useful information on this.

It might be a little late for you but I hope someone will benefit from this answer.